# Angular animate ng-src change

Tags: angularjs, css, jquery-animate

I have directive in angular and it simply changing images and I would like to animate when img is changing. But I have no idea how to do it. My directive is:

```
'user strict';
angular.module('app')
    .directive('card', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<img class="animated {{anim}}" ng-src="./img/cards/{{cardid}}.png"/>',
            scope: {
                cardid: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('cardid', function (value) {
                    scope.anim = 'cardAnim';
                    $timeout(function () {
                        scope.anim = '';
                    }, 1000);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

I'm 100% sure my class .cardAnim is working properly. Because when I add this class by browser manually everything is working just fine. And I also see that this class is added to the element but nothing is happening :(

Comment: "How do I use animations in my own directives?
Animations within custom directives can also be established by injecting $animate directly into your directive and making calls to it when needed." ?
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations (end of page)

Comment: Thanks for comment, I think my biggest problem is that I don't know how to use it together with ng-src. I'm able to make it with ng-if, ng-show and so on but not ng-src when the image is switching.

Comment: Are you sure it is supported for the ng-src directive when it is changing ?

Comment: I'm not and I didn't find any working solution. But there have to be any way how to make it.